# How to set herbstluftwm window transparency?

Tags: configuration, window-manager, tiling-wm, picom

In HLWM unfocused windows have their opacity reduced to something like 80%-90%. I would like to remove this feature and I can't seem to find the correct config options for this.

herbstlufwm version 0.8.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Herbstluftwm doesn't handle window opacity, this is handled by the compositor, in my case `picom`. In `picom.conf` I have set `inactive-opacity = 1` to obtain the desired outcome.